# Retrieve object associated in field based on logged in user Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have only two models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    player1 = models.ForeignKey('Player', related_name='player1' #other details)
    player2 = models.ForeignKey('Player', related_name='player2' #other details)
    player3 = models.ForeignKey('Player', related_name='player3' #other details)

class Player(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, #other details)
    art = models.URLField()
```

VIEW:

Once a user submits a link (custom validation in place) via a form, my view creates a Player object and then creates a Game object (if a Game object doesn't exist or is "full" because all player fields are populated) or it updates the next empty player1, player2, or player3 field by associating the newly created Player instance with it.

That works fine, but I'm stuck on how to query something for the next view/template.

**QUESTION:**

I want to display a Game object to a User who is logged in based on if they are a Player object associated with either player1, player2, or player3.

I *don't* want it to display just a recent Game object -- say using something like Game.objects.latest() -- because that might not be the one the User is associated with if other Game objects were created.

I cannot figure out how get the correct Game object. Best I can do is get the Player object associated with the User like is in a view:

```
def upload(request):
    mine = Player.objects.get(owner=request.user)
    
    context = {
         'mine': mine,
          }
```

But I want to get the Game object so I can display the other two players in the Game (or show a message like "waiting for players").

How?? Feels like it should be easy, but I've been stuck on this for a couple of days.

Comment: There can be multiple `Game`s, even where the same player appears as `player_1` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to display a Game object to a User who is logged in based on if they are a Player object associated with either `player1`, `player2`, or `player3`.

There can be *zero*, one, or *multiple*. Even if we would for example retain us to only `Game`s with the user as first player.

You can get a `QuerySet` of such `Game`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Q


def upload(request):
    mine = Player.objects.get(owner=request.user)
    games = Game.objects.filter(
        Q(player1=mine) | Q(player2=mine) | Q(player3=mine)
    )
    context = {'mine': mine, 'games': games}
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Profile` model to the `Game`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`player1`</s> relation to `games_as_player1`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see in the docs the reason for settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of User model. Also, I can see the reason for changing field names from player1 to games_as_player1. I'll need to think about it a little more, but it would make more sense when thinking about things in terms of finding not just the current Game, but also any previous (inactive/completed) Game. @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @postcardfiction: the `.filter(..)` will retrieve all games. Your `Game` currently doesn't seem to store whether the games are active, and when started. You can order these, so for example if the `Game` has a `DateTimeField` named `started`, you can get the most recent first with `Game.objects.order_by('-started')`.